# Google Apps Scriptのtry catchハンドリング

Tags: google-apps-script

グーグルフォームから入力されたパラメータを指定のスプレッドシートに転記するGASを作成しています。
そのスプレッドシートには、編集保護をかけて特定のユーザー権限のみ書き込めるようにしています。

アプリケーションのオーナー権限は統一しています。
このとき、GASを実行したところ以下のエラーでアプリケーションがストップしました。

```
2021/06/22 19:57:43 エラー 保護されているセルやオブジェクトを編集しようとしています。編集する必要がある場合は、スプレッドシートのオーナーに連絡して保護を解除してもらってください。
```

となります。そこで、try catchで次のように文章を囲みました。

```
try {
    // your script code here
      sheetdetail.getRange(lineNumberDetail, 1).setValue(applicationNumber);
      sheetdetail.getRange(lineNumberDetail, 2).setValue(detailsOfOrder);
      sheetdetail.getRange(lineNumberDetail, 3).setValue(appropriatenessOfTheApplicationAmount);
      sheetdetail.getRange(lineNumberDetail, 4).setValue(orderPeriod);
      sheetdetail.getRange(lineNumberDetail, 5).setValue(deliveryTime);
      sheetdetail.getRange(lineNumberDetail, 6).setValue(remarks);
      sheet.getRange(lineNumber, 33).setValue('未申請');
  } catch (e) {
    MailApp.sendEmail("********", "Error report", e.message);
  }
```

これでメールが送信されると思ったのですが、どうやらtryの中でアプリケーションが止まってしまっているように見えます。
こちらどういった原因が考えられますでしょうか？
詳しい方おられましたらご教示いただけますと幸いです。
現時点では

パーミッション系のエラーの場合try catchは無視されて実行できないと推察しております。

Comment: 今回の問題とは関係ありませんが、 `getRange` `setValue` 共に何度も呼ぶとアプリケーションが重くなるので、範囲指定を広げて一度に複数の値をセットすると読みやすく、筋がいいコードになります。また、文章を投稿するまえに一度読み直すことをおすすめします。

Comment: へぇ！そうなんですね、いや〜この辺り難しいですよね。複数の値をセットするとどう言ったものが格納されるかを読み解く時間が必要になるので、正直なところ迷ったんですよね。
僕も含めてチームの技術力が向上しましたら実施します！！

Answer (score 0):

GAS については詳しくないので少し調べた程度ですが、いきなり書き込もうとしてエラーハンドリングするより、まずは編集権限の有無を確認してから書き込む方が良さそうです。

例えば `canEdit()` で指定範囲の編集権限を確認できるようです。

**参考:**
[指定範囲に編集権限があるかどうか調べる：canEdit()](https://arukayies.com/gas/canedit)

> 指定範囲に編集権限がある場合にはtrue、権限がない場合はfalseを返します。
>
> ```
> function myFunction() {
>   const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[0];
>   const range = sheet.getRange('B2:D10');
>   range.canEdit()
> }
> ```

Comment: おおおおおおおおおおおおおお！！！！！！！！
やってみます！！！！！